# Azure Monitor in .NET Core

Tags: azure, .net-core

Using the preview package for Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor, I am trying to get metrics from Azure into a .NET Core application, but I am uncertain about what to input as "resourceUri".

```
var serviceCreds = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, clientId, secret);
var monitorClient = new MonitorManagementClient(serviceCreds);
monitorClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

var resourceUri = "";
var metrics = await monitorClient.Metrics.ListAsync(resourceUri: resourceUri, cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None);
```

What should I insert in the resourceUri variable, and where do I get this uri from in Azure? A lot of things are great about Azure, but not documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.

The resourceUri is in this format(this example is for web app, and you should replace with your real `subscriptionsId`, `resourceGroupsName` etc.):

```
/subscriptions/4d7e91d4-e930-4bb5-a93d-163aa358e0dc/resourceGroups/Default-Web-westus/providers/microsoft.web/serverFarms/DefaultServerFarm
```

You can find this information in the source code, [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/monitor/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor/tests/BasicTests/MetricsTests.cs#L19).

And for different resources, the format has a little difference, I add another resourceUri for blob storage:

```
/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxx/blobServices/default/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/ContainerCount
```

If you still have issues, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: That worked, sort of. I set the resourceUri to the following: "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/AppInsights/providers/microsoft.insights/components/Development"

But I only get one metric back ("availabilityResults/availabilityPercentage").

I can explain what I am trying to do. I would like to actually get all the Events that we have reported from our application. I am not sure that Metrics is the right thing for this.

Comment: @Christoffer, do you have more issues about it?

Comment: @Christoffer, for "get all the events", do you mean that the "event telemetry data" in application insights?

Comment: @Christoffer, if the Events is what I mentioned, then it's not. You can try the resourceUrl like "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/AppInsights/providers/microsoft.insights/components/DevelopmentcustomEvents/count". I don't have time to give it a try now, but will try it later.

Comment: No problems. According to the test code in the github repos, getting events is a bit different, but I did not manage to get it to work. But you have answered my initial question, I will make a new thread about this new issue. Thank you!

Comment: @Christoffer, ok, I'll take a look at the new post when I'm available.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61007517/custom-events-in-azure-monitor-for-net-core

Comment: @Christoffer, I'll work on the issue next day(it's public holiday in my country).

Comment: @IvanYang what to pass in odataquery on await monitorClient.ActivityLogs.ListAsync("odataquery") any idea

Comment: @gbbosmiya, I will take a look at it and update you later:).